# How to change the position of labels in nvd3 graph?

Tags: charts, nvd3.js

**Here is my current nvd3 pie chart**
[image: here is my nvd3 graph]

As you can see,I have all the labels in the top of the pie chart (indicated by the red box 1).
What I want to do is to,shift the position of these labels to the bottom of the pie chart (indicated by red box 2).

**Here is my nvd3 code**,which I have used to create this pie chart.

```
function graphDataStatsChart(sourceData) {
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
      .x(function(d) { return d.label })
      .y(function(d) { return d.value })
      .showLabels(true)     //Display pie labels
      .labelThreshold(.05)  //Configure the minimum slice size for labels to show up
      .labelType("percent") //Configure what type of data to show in the label. Can be "key", "value" or "percent"
      .donut(true)          //Turn on Donut mode. Makes pie chart look tasty!
      .donutRatio(0.35)     //Configure how big you want the donut hole size to be.
      ;

    d3.select("#chart1 svg")
        .datum(sourceData)
        .transition().duration(350)
        .call(chart);

  return chart;
});

};
```

Can any body suggest a way to do the above mentioned repositioning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to change a position of the legend container, e.g.

```
 d3.select(".nv-legendWrap")
  .attr("transform","translate(0,350)")
```

I've created an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c2Ls7qp9/).

Comment: its ok if you have only few items in data. http://www.s3blog.org/screengrab/images.html?id=9bf086c7e4a91a827c710b2daef15e65

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, with chart options, yo have `legendPosition`, but you can only place it either on top or to the right of the pie chart (see http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#pieChart, `legendPosition` values).

Answer (score 1):

Who use options.. Add this after the options ...

```
$timeout(function () {

      d3.selectAll('.nv-legendWrap').attr("transform","translate(0,300)");


  }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a better solution for this. Check out this [link](http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#pieChart) for more details.

```
chart.legendPosition("top");
chart.legendPosition("right");
chart.legendPosition("bottom");
chart.legendPosition("left");
```